# Is there a standard Haskell function with type: (Floating a, RealFrac b) => a -> b?

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass, coerce

I need to call `floor()` on a value, which is only constrained to be of class `Floating`, but `floor()` requires `RealFrac`.

**How can I do this?**

I'm perfectly willing to call `abs()` before calling `floor()`, but this alone seems insufficient to solve my constraint conflict.
And `coerce` complains that the two representations cannot be assumed equivalent, which isn't surprising.

It seems what I need is a function with type signature:

`(Floating a, RealFrac b) => a -> b`

And it seems (to me) perfectly legitimate to give some augmented version of `abs()` this signature.
Alas, a Hoogle search on the above type signature left me empty handed.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.
:)

Comment: It *definitely* isn't sensible to ask for a value with the type you propose. Can you add `RealFrac` to your constraints? If not, what type do you want to use this with? Perhaps we can help you do something sensible with that type -- but definitely not with *every* possible pairing of `Floating` and `RealFrac` instances.

Comment: I _agree_ with your request. IMO, the `Num` class should have and associated synonym `type Abs a :: *` and then `abs :: a -> Abs a` and `fromAbs :: Abs a -> a`. Then your constraint could be changed to `(Floating a, RealFrac (Abs a))`, and it would work.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, aside from `abs` and `signum`, `Num` is just ring operations. What do each of those add to a ring, mathematically?

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following instance of `Floating`:

```
import Control.Applicative

instance (Num a) => Num (e -> a) where
    (+) = liftA2 (+)
    (*) = liftA2 (*)
    (-) = liftA2 (-)
    abs = fmap abs
    signum = fmap signum
    negate = fmap negate
    fromInteger = pure . fromInteger

instance (Fractional a) => Fractional (e -> a) where
    fromRational = pure . fromRational
    recip = fmap recip
    (/) = liftA2 (/)

instance (Floating a) => Floating (e -> a) where
    pi = pure pi
    exp = fmap exp
    log = fmap log
    sin = fmap sin
    cos = fmap cos
    asin = fmap asin
    acos = fmap acos
    atan = fmap atan
    sinh = fmap sinh
    cosh = fmap cosh
    asinh = fmap asinh
    acosh = fmap acosh
    atanh = fmap atanh
```

Demo:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (sqrt sqrt 81)
    let f = sin^2 + cos^2
    print (f 42)
```

(This outputs `3.0000000000000004` and `1.0`.)

This makes functions an instance of `Floating`, but the code generalizes to all types that are `Monad`s or `Applicative`s.

Your hypothetical function would need to have the type

```
(Floating a, RealFrac b) => (e -> a) -> b
```

in this instance. We could set `a` and `b` to `Double`:

```
(e -> Double) -> Double
```

How do you implement that operation?

Remember that I said this generalizes to all Applicatives? We can replace `e ->` by `IO` in the above instances. Then the type you end up with gets even worse:

```
IO Double -> Double
```

The problem is that `Floating` can be anything that supports e.g. `exp` or `sin` operations (which could be purely symbolic operations e.g. on a syntax tree) while `RealFrac` must be a number (or something convertible to a number).

Comment: I'm not sure I like this example. Many `Num` instances, although you _can_ define them, don't really make sense mathematically – specifically, the `Num` instances for vector types like those from `hmatrix` and `linear` caused me all sorts of headache through weird bugs that _could_ have been caught by the type checker, if not for the `Num` instance that allowed innocuous number-literals to get inferred and unwanted vector type. The correct instance is usually `VectorSpace` and subclasses of that. For functions, I'm torn – this instance _makes_ sense, but there might still be better classes.

Comment: The `instance Num a => Num (IO a)` instance you propose is not lawful; there is a law saying `abs x * signum x = x`, and this is not validated for `x = putStrLn "hi!" >> return 42`. (But the rest of the argument is sound. Just a minor quibble.)

Comment: There's [**`Data.Complex.Complex`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Complex.html#t:Complex) as another example of a type that implements `Floating` but not `RealFrac` (and there really isn't a good instance of `RealFrac` for it).

Comment: @M.Aroosi Yeah, but you could sensibly apply `abs` to a complex number to get a real result, as suggested by OP.

Comment: You don't even need to go all the way to `IO` to for your "generalization" to become unlawful. Consider `Maybe`. You don't satisfy `x + negate x = fromInteger 0` when `x` is `Nothing`.

Comment: I think `e -> a` is an excellent example already. Since we don't know what `e` is, and since it could even be something like `Void`, there's absolutely no way to use the argument function! So a function with the requested polymorphic type must be constant and therefore not a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Can you afford an `Ord` constraint?

```hs
module FBound (ffloor, fceil) where
import Data.List (foldl')

-- |
-- >>> ffloor . fromInteger <$> [-10..10]
-- [-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
-- >>> ffloor . (+0.001) . fromInteger <$> [-10..10]
-- [-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
-- >>> ffloor . (+0.999) . fromInteger <$> [-10..10]
-- [-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
ffloor :: (Ord a, Floating a, Integral b) => a -> b
ffloor a | a >= 0     = ffloor' a
         | otherwise  = negate $ fceil' (-a)

-- |
-- >>> fceil. fromInteger <$> [-10..10]
-- [-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
-- >>> fceil . (-0.001) . fromInteger <$> [-10..10]
-- [-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
-- >>> fceil . (-0.999) . fromInteger <$> [-10..10]
-- [-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
fceil :: (Ord a, Floating a, Integral b) => a -> b
fceil a | a >= 0     = fceil' a
        | otherwise  = negate $ ffloor' (-a)

-- given a >= 0, ffloor' a <= a < ffloor' a + 1
ffloor' :: (Ord a, Floating a, Integral b) => a -> b
ffloor' = foldl' roundDown 0 . reverse . takeWhile (>=1) . iterate (/2)

-- given a >= 0, fceil' a - 1 < a <= fceil' a
fceil' :: (Ord a, Floating a, Integral b) => a -> b
fceil' a = ffloor' (a/2) `roundUp` a

-- given 2*i <= a < 2*i + 2, roundDown i a <= a < roundDown i a + 1
roundDown :: (Ord a, Num a, Integral b) => b -> a -> b
roundDown i a | a < fromIntegral (2*i + 1) = 2*i
              | otherwise                  = 2*i + 1

-- given 2*i <= a < 2*i + 2, roundUp i a - 1 < a <= roundUp i a
roundUp :: (Ord a, Num a, Integral b) => b -> a -> b
roundUp i a | a == fromIntegral (2*i)     = 2*i
            | a <= fromIntegral (2*i + 1) = 2*i + 1
            | otherwise                   = 2*i + 2
```